# Questions about offensive language - should they be allowed, and should we take any special precautions?

Tags: discussion

I asked: [How to say or suggest in an informal (and possibly rude) way that someone can be disregarded?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2046/f-em-how-to-say-or-suggest-in-an-informal-way-that-someone-can-be-disre), and noticed that it was quickly met with a flag and a couple of downvotes.

On the other hand, [How to spell final "shhhh!" in gangster speak?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/304/how-to-spell-final-shhhh-in-gangster-speak/306) was highly-upvoted.

Perhaps there is a difference in that the first one has potentially offensive English in the example sentence, while the second is talking about offensive Korean language; nevertheless, it is the language I was looking for a translation for.

Other sites in the network don't seem to have an issue with such questions - e.g. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155664/how-many-different-parts-of-speech-can-the-f-word-be-used-as/155673 - but of course, we are free to make our own guidelines.

Do we want to allow such questions, and should we take any special precautions?

Comment: I think that as long as the examples are hidden, this type of question is okay.

Comment: may be there should be a profanity tag or some indication in the title itself that it's about rude language, to help beginners filter it out more easily

Comment: @user17915 I've added an '[tag:offensive]' tag. I had put the 'starred-out' language in the title partly as a warning but maybe the tag is a bit more subtle (I've now removed that from the title).

Answer (score 5):

(Now that the flags have been dealt with, I'll post my personal view)

I think of Stack Exchange Language sites as, in general, a place to discuss topics from an adult technical/academic perspective. In alignment with that, I think all Korean words, even offensive ones, should be allowed on the site as part of genuine questions and answers.

As this is an English/Korean site I would also assume that offensive English vocabulary would be allowed, where necessary or helpful, as part of genuine examples, explanations, and so on.

I don't think genuine posts should be flagged as 'rude or abusive' simply because they are *about* rude language - only when the posts are themselves directly rude or abusive in their nature.

I do think that it's fair to limit use of offensive language to the minimum needed to make the point.